# I am having selenium script in Java, i need to run it every one hour automatically with out my intervention.How to do it?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cloud

I want to run my Java selenium script every one hour.I want to do it without Human intervention.How to do it?

Can i do it by keeping my piece of code in cloud or any online IDE which runs it every one hour?
Please help in this case.

I have seen some people suggesting Windows Task scheduler,but the file should run even my computer is shutdown.

Comment: you can use jenkins to achieve this

Comment: How will it run if your computer is shut down?

Comment: Hi santhosh,can u explain it a bit??

Comment: Can you please give us some background on this.

Comment: @sathvikvutukuri Can you consider showcasing your work please? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Windows scheduled task. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx

Cron job https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-schedule-routine-tasks-with-cron-and-anacron-on-a-vps

I would use something like Jenkins, or  AWS to run your job (on a schedule).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create tests packed as an executable the easiest way may be to run a CRON job or a Windows scheduled task.

Or

2. If you have  Hudson (or another continuous integration system like jenkin ) can be use for it and is almost certainly better long term strategies.

Answer (score 0):

However this question is quite broad, I can give you a general approach with a suggestion. That you need is to persist the application where is the script, method or whatsoever included and call it every 60 minutes.

In general, I'd suggest you create a web service and deploy it on Azure's Tomcat servlet container. You need a web page available online, where you can periodically call with AJAX the Selenium method mapped to the exact URL.

The disadvantage may be the complexity of the client-side and server-side concept if you have the lack of experience. However, you can monitor the activity and the results for your own and scale the web service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any only CI environments for this task. For example free and easy to configure is [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org) it has integration with github and lot of documentation for how to run it.